# Connect two raspberry pi via usb to one pc

Tags: networking, usb, pi-zero, vnc

I have one raspberry pi zero connected to my windows pc via usb.  It is connected as an RNDIS Gadget. I use VNC to operate it headless. I would like to connect a second pi zero in the same way.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

To be specific the problem I'm having is how to identify the second pi.  VNC only sees the one "raspberrypi.local"

Comment: Unsure, but test if this is because they both have the same default name.  Connect one, run `sudo raspi-config` and choose 1 (System Options), then S4 (Hostname) and try renaming one so they no longer have the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use multiple Pi (using ANY method) you should change the hostname.

Change using the menu item in raspi-config; DO NOT attempt to edit files as this this is more complex and error prone.

I have written a script to automate the process. This is handy when you have 9 Pi which you can find on this site if interested.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I will add there is an additional element that needs to be done in Windows.  The two RNDIS Gadgets need to be bridged and THEN shared with internet connection.  I found instructions for that [here](https://superuser.com/questions/656998/windows-7-share-internet-connection-with-multiple-network-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

It is most definitely possible. You will have to change the hostname of one of your pi's though. The hostname you are connecting to, raspberrypi.local, is made possible through multicast DNS using the avahi daemon. How to change the hostname has been described in an excellent answer [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/78092/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-rebooting).